# Should I be worried that Git Bash is telling me that I am "REVERTING"?

Tags: git, revert

One of our developers did a merge on the origin/master which broke our build. After `git pull` on my local master, I did a revert and pushed it back to master.

> git revert -m 1 cb6ec80
>   git push

Now my changes are in origin/master. 
Everything seems to be fine except for the fact that Git Bash seems to indicate that I'm not done with the following prompt:

> racompton@soandso ~/Projects/MyProject (master|REVERTING)

It should just say (master) instead of (master|REVERTING). I can say that I have been able create new local branches, push them to origin and do pull requests. I get the updated code when I do a git pull origin/master, yet the prompt still looks like I have something left to do.

Have I broken something here?

Comment: The `|REVERTING` means you have not yet *finished* your revert. You're still in the middle of the operation. You have not pushed the commit that reverts `cb6ec80` because it does not yet exist. Git is waiting for you to run `git revert --continue` or `git revert --abort`, before taking you out of the "still reverting" mode.

Comment: After calling `$ git revert --continue` . 
Now I get this:  
error: could not revert 4f7c3f2... User Story 71633 . 
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths . 
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'  
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit' .

Comment: 4f7c3f2 is the SHA1 just before the merge on the errant branch.

Comment: Hm, sounds like you were in the middle of a multi-commit revert and it's doing the next commit wherever you are now (which is probably the wrong place to finish the in-progress revert). You might want to save the current branch name / hash ID pairing somewhere and use `--abort` to terminate the reversion, which may yank your current branch name off its current hash ID. You can then restore the branch name (`git branch -f` or `git reset --hard`) if/as needed, and you'll be out of the "revert in progress" mode.

Comment: Your sample command, on the other hand, is just a single revert of a merge. So maybe that's NOT the case, and you just need to finish the one revert. It's not really clear here.

Comment: @torek --continue moved me back further than I wanted. I saw a lot of previous changes. So I did an --abort, and now it's as I expected to turn out to begin with. Thanks to you it's working, but I don't know why.

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure what was going on. You can cherry-pick and revert single commits while cherry-picking or reverting multiple commits; perhaps that was what happened? But then your `|REVERTING` mode should have been there for a long time, up to this point. But whatever, it's cleared out now :-)